# Categories that have Questions, CRUD in one view feels chaotic

Tags: gui-design, dashboard, listview

[image]

I've been thinking about this design for a while, and I couldn't find any good examples online, this is a system where there are **Categories** and **Questions**, and they are both translatable.

So in my example, I'm looking for a way so that the user has a view (or multiple views), where they can CRUD Categories, and CRUD questions for these categories.

The whole translation aspect is going to be in the "Edit" modal, this feels right, the modal will include fields for all languages.

The biggest issue I see here

- Should this be 2 views instead of one? I do feel it's important that they see the categories that are available, and all questions, that's why I tried to do this in one view

**Does anyone know of a design pattern that addresses a case like this?**

Answer (score 1):

You could show all question and then add a filter to show only the items you want by category, language, etc.

[image: design showing a questions list]

It's OK if the user clicks on the drop down and sees the available categories from there, a bit less clatter in my opinion

As for viewing and creating categories, you can add more features to the drop-down

[image: A drop down with a bit more spice]

Now, the "+ Create Category Chicken" is a prompt that should show when someone tries using the category "chicken" but it doesn't exist yet.

It can bring up a dialog box, with something like this:

[image: dialog box with category translations]

But given that you want to be able to delete categories as well, a new view would be a good idea. I guess this depends on what has already been implemented and what yourself and the devs agree upon.

Comment: How would I create a new category, using this view? It is less cluttered, agreed! Maybe the issue is that there's the management of categories and questions, all in one view

Comment: @MiguelStevens when the user clicks on the category drop down, you could add a search bar in the drop-down. If the category doesn't exist, you can create the category. I'm updating the answer above to show how this could look

Comment: @MiguelStevens does the update add more clarity? If I'm missing something, please do tell and I'll adjust accordingly

Comment: thanks for adding this change! It does make sense, however a category also has translations, so how would you provide a button to open the translations modal for editing a category? Categories should also be able to be removed.

Comment: @MiguelStevens that last bit "Categories should also be able to be removed" is what I was worried about. Yea that means a new view needs to be made, but the questions section can remain as shown above to make the creation of questions a lot easier.

Comment: @MiguelStevens I just realised that you could add an additional dialog box when the "+Create Category..." button is clicked and there the user can add more translations, I believe I answered another question of yours with an answer that would fit what the dialog box could look like. I can do one for this answer if it fits what you are comfortable with implementing.

Answer (score 1):

What I think is when there are so many similar options repeated, something is wrong at the UX level:

[image]

Perhaps you should study another type of interface, not as a final alternative, but to discover how to solve the original. For example:

- Make each item selectable
- Visually unify the actions: <kbd>Add</kbd>, <kbd>Remove</kbd>
  and <kbd>Edit</kbd>
- If the only action regarding a question is to change the category, I don't think a category menu is necessary, just a drop-down menu on the right (or left) that allows defining the new category of the question.

[image]